# linux + how to verify VM defintion disk after redhat installation

Tags: linux, redhat, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

We have couple of Linux servers all them are VM red hat Linux ( and they created by the Vsphere client , )

I want to know how we can capture on the Linux OS the following

1.Thick provision lazy zeroed

2.Thick provision eager zeroed

3.Thin provision

Is it possible to find files/conf on the linux redhat

And verify by this files the definition (1 or 2 or 3 ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not directly possible, as the client know nothing about the provisioned storage.

You can infer some information using specific client-side benchmarks, though.

Comment: so if this isnt from the cient then how to verify by VSphere client GUI the disk defintion?

Comment: It should be quite simple... have a look [here](http://adriank.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/VMware_virtual_machine_thin_provisioned_disk_size_greyed_out_1.png)

Comment: I mean how to verify if defintion is thin ot other ( thick )

Comment: From the screenshot above, it should be sufficient to open the VM hardware page, select the virtual disk, and check the allocation data on the right. In general, I strongly suspect the VSphere Client should show the disk type quite clearly.